# Memory leakage while using C# dll into MFC code

Tags: c#, c++

I want create parser for reading Text of RTF file.
so I have created a dll in C# using RichTextBox.
after that I convert it from dll to tlb.
and calling it from cpp.

But it produce memory leakage in loop and application memory keeps on increasing.

I am attaching both code snipet..

Please help me.

Thank you

```
public string Convert(string strRTFTxt)
    {
        string path = strRTFTxt;

        //Create the RichTextBox. (Requires a reference to System.Windows.Forms.)
        System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();

        // Get the contents of the RTF file. When the contents of the file are   
        // stored in the string (rtfText), the contents are encoded as UTF-16.  
        string rtfText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

        // Display the RTF text. This should look like the contents of your file.
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(rtfText);

        // Use the RichTextBox to convert the RTF code to plain text.
        rtBox.Rtf = rtfText;
        string plainText = rtBox.Text;

        rtBox.Clear();
        rtBox.Dispose();
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(plainText);

        // Output the plain text to a file, encoded as UTF-8. 
        //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"output.txt", plainText);

        return plainText;
    }
```

Cpp code where I am reading the text from dll.

```
    long lResult =0;
std::string str ;

char* tcFileName = new char[m_strFilePath.GetLength()+1]; 

USES_CONVERSION;

strcpy (tcFileName, T2A (m_strFilePath));


printf("char * text: %s\n", tcFileName);


BSTR bstrText = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR(tcFileName);
BSTR  bstrReturnValue;
wprintf(L"BSTR text: %s\n", bstrText);

iRTFConverter->Convert(bstrText,&bstrReturnValue);
//iRTFConverter->
CString strCIFContent(bstrReturnValue);

ParseString(strCIFContent);

delete []tcFileName;
tcFileName = NULL;

iRTFConverter->Release();
SysFreeString(bstrText);
bstrText = NULL;
SysFreeString(bstrReturnValue);
```

Comment: What's happening in `ParseString`?

Comment: The behavior of the garbage collector used in C# is notoriously poorly understood.  One standard problem when used in interop code is not creating enough garbage to coax it into doing its job.  Another is using a poor memory profiler, Task Manager is particularly poor at showing what is really going on.  Find out whether you *really* have a leak or are just misunderstanding memory management by testing this code.  Simply run it a million times.  If the test bombs with OOM then you *know* you have a real leak.

Comment: Mr. Thorsten Dittmar    ParseString is simply extract the text line by line and push it into a stack.